# Trying to download a file in a loop with node.js, but seems to get some sync problems

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I'm trying to make a simple program in node.js that will download the same file with some interval. If the downloaded file is newer than the previous, then it will be saved in a new filename with the help of a counter.

If it's a new file, then I want to save it in the last_unique.jpg name and use it to compare next time the file will be downloaded. But it doesn't seem to work. For test, I just have an empty last_unique.jpg that I would expect to be overwritten. But it never is, so every time the jpg file is downloaded, it is unique and saves it in file3.jpg, file3.jpg, etc.

However, the output also looks like maybe some async issues? It skips the first couple of times.

OUTPUT:

```
downloading 1
downloading 2
downloading 3
Unique file spotted!
downloading 4
Unique file spotted!
downloading 5
Unique file spotted!
downloading 6
Unique file spotted!
downloading 7
Unique file spotted!
downloading 8
Unique file spotted!
```

Here is the code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const md5File = require('md5-file');
const fileToDownload = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg";
var counter = 0;

function request() {
        counter = counter + 1
        console.log("downloading " + counter);
        const save = fs.createWriteStream("last_download.jpg");

        http.get(fileToDownload, function(response) {
                response.pipe(save)
        });

        const hash1 = md5File.sync('last_download.jpg');
        const hash2 = md5File.sync('last_unique.jpg');

        // it is a new file
        if (hash1.localeCompare(hash2) != 0) {
                console.log('Unique file spotted!');
                fs.copyFileSync('last_download.jpg','last_unique.jpg');
                fs.copyFileSync('last_unique.jpg','file' + counter + '.jpg');
        }
}

setInterval(request, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const md5File = require('md5-file');
const fileToDownload = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg";
var counter = 0;

function request() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    console.log("downloading " + counter);
    const save = fs.createWriteStream("last_download.jpg");

    http.get(fileToDownload, function(response) {
        response.pipe(save);
        response.on('end',function () {
            save.end();

        })
    });


    save.on('finish',function () {

        const hash1 = md5File.sync('last_download.jpg');
        const hash2 = md5File.sync('last_unique.jpg');

        console.log(hash1,hash2);
        // it is a new file
        if (hash1.localeCompare(hash2) != 0) {
            console.log('Unique file spotted!');
            fs.copyFileSync('last_download.jpg','last_unique.jpg');
            fs.copyFileSync('last_unique.jpg','file' + counter + '.jpg');
        }

    });



}

setInterval(request, 3000);
```

You need to listen for the finish event on the stream otherwise it maybe the case that you call the copy function before the stream has completely been written. Hence a partial image is copied from the **last_download.jpg** to **last_unique.jpg** which means the hashes would be different. This is due the asynchronous nature of copying and http request.

Comment: Thank you. This is excellent feedback. I still have a poor understand on the event driven nature of javascript.